# auto -instantiate a session bean?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a session bean

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>vdcAddBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.cloud.appsportfolio.jsf.vdc.beans.VDCAddBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Now, I am injecting this bean into a request one:

```
<managed-bean>
      <managed-bean-name>providerSelectionBean</managed-bean-name>
      <managed-bean-class>com.cloud.appsportfolio.jsf.sourcing.ProviderSelectionBean</managed-bean-class>
      <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
      <managed-property>
        <property-name>vdcAddBean</property-name>
        <property-class>com.cloud.appsportfolio.jsf.vdc.beans.VDCAddBean</property-class>
        <value>#{sessionScope.vdcAddBean}</value> 
      </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Well, when I'm accessing vdcAddBean in `providerSelectionBean` java code, I receive a NPE because `vdcAddBean` is not yet initialized. If I'm going first in my menu, in a page which has `vdcAddBean` in the back-end and comes back to `providerSelectionBean` all works great because it seems that `vdcAddBean` was already initialized.

The question is: *how I can force vdcAddBean to be initialized (if it's null) when accessing `providerSelectionBean` bean?*

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to access vdcAddBean in the Constructor of providerSelectionBean and getting a null pointer? If so you can probably move the logic that depends on vdcAddBean into the setVdcAddBean() method and avoid the NP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<value>#{sessionScope.vdcAddBean}</value>
```

by

```
<value>#{vdcAddBean}</value>
```

to get JSF to autocreate the bean.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course, it is best to avoid such solutions.

Answer (score 1):

JSF managed session beans are stored within the ExternalContext, you can retrieve a map with all of them using the following method, getSessionMap.

The key to this map should be the managed-bean-name, so perhaps you can check for null and if so then try instantiating your bean and putting it directly into the sessionMap?

Comment: Indeed, thanks: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()   .getSessionMap().put("vdcAddBean", vdcAddBean);`